# I live in a pretty complex social structure, apparently

Tags: word, knowledge

> At my core I am pretty dense. So I like to stay grounded and don't really change where I am at. But there are more who are denser than me! Compared to them I change a lot more freely. But from your perspective you have always thought of me as a pretty dynamic person :) But then you learn you aren't always right in your assumption, maybe you aren't as dense as you thought.

Who am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this

> The sun

?

> We think it moves - 'cause it does, relative to us, and early man didn't make that distinction. It's also dense at its core, but other stars are denser. It changes appearance regularly with sunspots/flares.

Comment: Good job! You got it!

Comment: To be technical, the sun moves relative to the universe "at large". But I digress. And I'm probably not thinking straight here haha

Comment: the third sentence is imply that actually.

Comment: Ah, nice. Looks like some of that still went over my head. Good riddle!